# How can I direct gnome-tweak-tool to list extensions alphabetically?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

On Ubuntu 11.10, using gnome-tweak-tool (3.2.0-0ubuntu1), I have great difficulty finding specific extensions.  The ordering seems random.

I have looked and looked.. but I do not see any ordering options.

Is there a way to change the ordering to be alphabetic?  Or by provider, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't consider myself a pro python coder, so this may not be the most efficient way to go.  In fact, I had to do some [research for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) because it's been a while since I've used python.

If you open `/usr/share/pyshared/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_shell_extensions.py`, and add the following import at the top of the file:

`from operator import itemgetter`

Then at the bottom of the script, modify the try block to sort extensions (around line 154):

```
        try:
             #add a tweak for each installed extension
             extensions = shell.list_extensions().values()
             for extension in sorted(extensions, key=itemgetter('name')):
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a way!  I need to study python.  That worked excellently.  I'm set... until the next update to the tweak tool! lol

Comment: @TheGeeko61 No problem! I started learning python a long time ago (around 1999, maybe?), but I was easily annoyed by significant whitespace and decided to learn Ruby instead. When you do study it, use a good editor like vim and the whitespace becomes less of a headache.